# Substracting Three Integers in Assembly (MASM)

Tags: assembly, integer, masm, irvine32

Using the **AddSub** program, write a program that subtracts three integers using only 16-bit registers. Insert a **call DumpRegs** statement to display the register values.

AddSub Example Program:

```
TITLE Add and Subtract, Version 2 (AddSub2.asm)
; This program adds and subtracts 32-bit unsigned
; integers and stores the sum in a variable.
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
val1 DWORD 10000h
val2 DWORD 40000h
val3 DWORD 20000h
finalVal DWORD ?
.code
main PROC
mov eax,val1 ; start with 10000h
add eax,val2 ; add 40000h
sub eax,val3 ; subtract 20000h
mov finalVal,eax ; store the result (30000h)
call DumpRegs ; display the registers
exit
main ENDP
END main
How does it work? First,
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. As you're new around here, some friendly advice - include in your question what you've tried and exactly where you're stuck. It'll help you get better answers. Nobody will write your code for you. Also, given this is assembly, for what platform?

Comment: which assembly language? what is the size of the numbers? A lot of things need to be clarified. And the most important thing is what did you try?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Take a look into the profile of the OP especially the "seen" section. Do you really believe that you'll get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the "addSub"-program, you probably only have to know the theory behind signed integers, (two's complement), and the opcode for 0-x. (NEG)

Eight bit example, 5-10-20

```
ldi a,5
ldi b,10
ldi c,20

neg b
neg c
addc a,b
addc a,c
```

ok?

Answer (score -1):

Question is:Using the ADDSUB program from the section 3.2 as a reference, write a program that subtracts three integers only 16-bit registers.  Insert a cal DumpRegs statement to display the register values

Work is:

```
TITLE Add and Subtract      (AddSub.asm)

; Program Assignment 1 - Subtracting Three Integers   
; Using the AddSub program From Section 3.2 as a Reference,  
; Write a program that subtracts three Integer using only 16-bit     registers,  
; Insert a call DumpRegs statement to display the register values.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .code
 main PROC

 mov eax, 90000h    ;EAX = 10000h  
 sub eax, 40000h    ;EAX = 50000h   
 sub eax, 20000h    ;EAX = 30000h   
 call DumpRegs                ; display registers    

   exit    

   main ENDP   

   END main
```

Comment: **only 16-bit registers.**